# apt-mirrorコマンドが上手くいきません

Tags: ubuntu, apt

HPEの物理サーバにUbuntu 22.04をインストールして、サーバはオフラインで運用しています。
オフライン環境のため、パッケージのインストールができず、事前にパッケージのdebファイルをtarで固めて置いておくことになっています。（以下のファイル全て）
上記のパッケージファイルを一個一個ダウンロードしていると気が遠くなる作業なので、Ubuntu/Debian ではパッケージリポジトリをミラーリングする apt-mirrorコマンドを使用しようと思っています。
https://ja.linux-console.net/?p=1392#gsc.tab=0

apt-mirror を実行してみたのですが以下のエラーが表示され上手くいきません。
何かご存知であればご教示いただけると助かります。
設定値はデフォルトで変更してません。（強調表記になるみたいなので#の数を増やしたり、リンクにならないようにhttpのhを削除しています。）

エラー内容

```
root@testserver:~# apt-mirror
Downloading 162 index files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Fri Jan 6 06:59:43 2023
[20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]...
End time: Fri Jan 6 07:08:36 2023

Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-security/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-security/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-security/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-security/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-updates/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-updates/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-updates/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-updates/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 507.
Processing translation indexes: [TTT]

Downloading 0 translation files using 0 threads...
Begin time: Fri Jan 6 07:08:36 2023
[0]...
End time: Fri Jan 6 07:08:36 2023

Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 653.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 653.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 653.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 653.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-security/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 653.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-security/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 653.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-security/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 653.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-security/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 653.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-updates/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 653.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-updates/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 653.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-updates/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 653.
Failed to open Release file from ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-updates/Release at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 653.
Processing DEP-11 indexes: [DDD]

Downloading 0 dep11 files using 0 threads...
Begin time: Fri Jan 6 07:08:36 2023
[0]...
End time: Fri Jan 6 07:08:36 2023

apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful/main/source/Sources in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful/restricted/source/Sources in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful/universe/source/Sources in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful/multiverse/source/Sources in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful-security/main/source/Sources in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful-security/restricted/source/Sources in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful-security/universe/source/Sources in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful-security/multiverse/source/Sources in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful-updates/main/source/Sources in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful-updates/restricted/source/Sources in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful-updates/universe/source/Sources in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful-updates/multiverse/source/Sources in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful/main/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful/universe/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/artful-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
Processing indexes: [SSSPPP]

0 bytes will be downloaded into archive.
Downloading 0 archive files using 0 threads...
Begin time: Fri Jan 6 07:08:36 2023
[0]...
End time: Fri Jan 6 07:08:36 2023

0 bytes in 0 files and 0 directories can be freed.
Run /var/spool/apt-mirror/var/clean.sh for this purpose.

Running the Post Mirror script ...
(/var/spool/apt-mirror/var/postmirror.sh)

Post Mirror script has completed. See above output for any possible errors.
```

設定

```
root@testserver:~# cat /etc/apt/mirror.list
############# config ##################

####### set base_path /var/spool/apt-mirror

####### set mirror_path $base_path/mirror
####### set skel_path $base_path/skel
####### set var_path $base_path/var
####### set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
####### set defaultarch
####### set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
####### set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads 20
set _tilde 0

############# end config ##############

deb ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted universe multiverse
deb ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
#deb ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse

clean ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

root@testserver:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
####### See ttp://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
####### newer versions of the distribution.
deb ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
####### deb-src ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted

######## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
######## distribution.
deb ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted
####### deb-src ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted

######## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
######## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
######## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
####### deb-src ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
deb ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe
####### deb-src ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe

######## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
######## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
######## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
######## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
######## security team.
deb ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
####### deb-src ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
deb ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse
####### deb-src ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse

######## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as ######## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes ######## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features. ######## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review ######## or updates from the Ubuntu security team. deb ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse ####### deb-src ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse deb ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted ####### deb-src ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted deb ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe ####### deb-src ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe deb ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse ####### deb-src ttp://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
root@testserver:~# lsblk
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0 7:0 0 79.9M 1 loop /snap/lxd/22923
loop1 7:1 0 62M 1 loop /snap/core20/1587
loop3 7:3 0 49.6M 1 loop /snap/snapd/17883
loop4 7:4 0 63.3M 1 loop /snap/core20/1778
loop5 7:5 0 103M 1 loop /snap/lxd/23541
sda 8:0 0 430.1G 0 disk
tqsda1 8:1 0 1M 0 part
tqsda2 8:2 0 2G 0 part /boot
mqsda3 8:3 0 428.1G 0 part
mqubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0 0 100G 0 lvm /
sr0 11:0 1 1024M 0 rom
```

Comment: 実際に確認すると判るかと思いますが、`http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/Release` は現時点(2023/1/10)では存在しません。現状では LTS と develop のリポジトリのみが存在するだけです。今回は Ubuntu 22.04(jammy) のリポジトリだけを mirroring すればよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 2022年にリリースされたものは Ubuntu 22.04 LTS "Jammy Jellyfish" それに Ubuntu 22.10 "Kinetic Kudu",
2023年にリリース予定は Ubuntu 23.04 “Lunar Lobster” (これらはアルファベット順)。
あるリリース (質問の Ubuntu 22.04) に対し別リリースのパッケージを入れるとトラブルのもと, 最悪は再インストールすることになるでしょう (Debianパッケージ入れてしまうとかも同様)。正しいパッケージを選択してください。(あと, 依存パッケージもあるので, オフラインで行なう場合そのことを考慮する必要があるかも)

Comment: ご教示いただいた通り上記のURLは存在しませんでした。。こちらを削除し、Ubuntu22.04のリポジトリを使用したところ解決に至りました。ありがとうございます！！

Answer (score 1):

前提知識として、Ubuntu/Debian ではパッケージを取得する際、OS バージョンに対応したコードネームを使用します。

あなたが使用している Ubuntu 22.04 の場合、`/etc/apt/sources.list` の中に記載されている "jammy" がコードネームになります。

```
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
```

---

さて、apt-mirror の設定ファイル (`/etc/apt/mirror.list`) で初期設定では "artful" となっており、これに対応するのは Ubuntu 17.10 になります。とても古いバージョンなのでミラーサイトにもファイルが見つからずにダウンロードエラーになっている状態なのだと思われます。

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted universe multiverse
                                     ~~~~~~
```

まずは最低限、こちらを自分が使用しているバージョンのコードネームに書き換える必要があります。

**書き換え例:**

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jemmy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jemmy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jemmy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jemmy-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jemmy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

**参考:** (OSバージョンは異なるので適時読み替えてください)
[apt-mirrorの設定 | Ubuntu20.04 ローカルにアーカイブミラーを立ててみる](https://rohhie.net/ubuntu20-04-try-to-set-up-a-local-archive-mirror/#Build-ConfigureAptMirror)

Comment: ご教示いただきましてありがとうございます。前提知識が不足していたためご教示いただいた方法で解決に至りました。ありがとうございます！！

Comment: お役に立てたようで何よりです。ひとつ前の質問も含めて、もし解決した場合には [回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) してもらえると励みになります。